# Сортировка выборки строк по алфавитно-числовому кортежу

Tags: php, mysql, sql, база-данных

Интересует, каким образом можно реализовать, вроде как, незамысловатую задачу.

Есть список локаций. И заполняется он, приблизительно, такими значениями:

- Баскетбольная площадка
- Столовая
- Шатёр #1
- Шатёр #2
- Шатёр #3
- Шатёр #4
- Шатёр #5
- Шатёр #6
- Шатёр #7
- Шатёр #8
- Шатёр #9
- Шатёр #10
- Шатёр #11

Я не зря написал так много их, поскольку в этом и заключается загвоздка. В примере выше всё отсортировано так, как должно быть.
Если же написать стандартный код для сортировки:
`select * from my_table order by name`, то на выходе получим:

- Баскетбольная площадка
- Столовая
- Шатёр #1
- **Шатёр #10**
- **Шатёр #11**
- Шатёр #2
- Шатёр #3
- Шатёр #4
- Шатёр #5
- Шатёр #6
- Шатёр #7
- Шатёр #8
- Шатёр #9

Думаю, многие поняли причину этой проблемы. Order By сортирует это всё как строки, а вот людям это кажется совершенно нелогичным. Каким образом можно решить данную проблему? Рабочих примеров найти не удалось. Искал.

*Кроме символа "#", иногда, могут указать "№", но это не учитывается в рамках задачи. Указываю такую информацию, на случай если будут предложения делить строку путём разреза, как это в PHP делается с помощью функции explode. Просто уже видел такие предложения в аналогичных вопросах на StackOverflow.*

Comment: Тебе нужна __натуральная сортировка__ (natural sort), судя по гуглу в мускуле ее нет, поэтому костыли.

Comment: @u_mulder я понимаю, что костыли. Просто сам не силён в SQL, иначе бы просто не обращался за помощью.

Comment: Надо взять все что вернул запрос и отсортировать методами php  учетом натуральной сортировки - `natcasesort`.

Comment: @u_mulder очень весело это будет наблюдать, когда ещё используется пагинация от движка.

Comment: https://snipplr.com/view/41275

Comment: А числительные всегда в конце ? Как сортировать строки, в случае например 'Шахтер 12 A5 C' ?

Comment: @Kirill читал об этом

Comment: @Mike всегда в конце или их вовсе может не быть

Comment: Сейчас реализовал с помощью натуральной сортировки, но на пагинации, встроенной в Laravel, это никак не отразится, поскольку там всё работает сразу через запросы к БД.